# Building and testing intermediate spiderMonkey check ins

Tags: javascript, linux, cvs, jit, spidermonkey

I am trying to build and test an intermediate spiderMonkey check-in/ gitHub commit.

1) When trying to run custom JavaScript file over released v31/38 of spiderMonkey, errors specifying some variables which are defined out of scope were encountered.

> " warning: offsetof within non-standard-layout type ‘js::PerThreadDataFriendFields::RuntimeDummy’ is undefined [-Winvalid-offsetof]
>   static const size_t RuntimeMainThreadOffset = offsetof(RuntimeDummy, mainTh
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmozjs-31
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Similar errors were found to be unresolved in the publicly shared google group of this mailing list.

2) When executing steps mentioned on Mozilla webpage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Source_Code/CVS) to test branch versions of SpiderMonkey via CVS platform, I get:

> " Unknown host cvs-mirror.mozilla.org"

Which seems to be unresolved on bugzilla.

How do I go ahead with testing a gitHub commit dated Aug 2014?

Comment: i am running into same problem. Did you find an answer? i tried cloning the github repo. Github has commits only from nov 2007.